# Filter and sort table with input fields with values, datatables.net

Tags: sorting, filter, datatables, edit

is it possible to sort and filter a databable.net-table if there are only input fields in the single rows that got some values?

I need it to be able to order my records on my edit page!

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can,

But in that case you have to put `data-search` and `data-order` attributes properly, check this [demo](http://codepen.io/MWalid/pen/yDEsF), and have a look at the [reference](http://datatables.net/manual/data).

Comment: Wow, thats simply awesome simple.